# performance of non supported languages on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

AWS Lambda obviously supports Node.js, Python and C# out of the box, but I also know that we can bundle up different languages such as PHP,Ruby,GO etc. into our Lambda code and then execute them via one of the previous languages. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

Are there any significant performance hits in doing this? Obviously there will be some overhead in calling the external process, but I'm wondering if it's worthwhile in doing this if your familiar with another language runtime then it would be in just learning/using one of the 'native' languages such as Node? (aside from having to learn a tiny bit of one of the languages to launch your child process)

I'm not sure how the underlying infrastructure of the Lambda would work. And obviously if a function is used infrequently it will take time to 'spin up' every time it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sparta Project](http://gosparta.io/docs/limitations/) reports an overhead of ~700ms, and I have seen a similar result (possibly less) using [Pharo Smalltalk](https://pharo.org) with my [PharoLambda](https://gitlab.com/macta/PharoLambda) example.